# adding marker to map in NativeScript app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, nativescript

I'm building a `NativeScript` app using the [`nativescript-google-maps-sdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-google-maps-sdk).

I have added an eventlistener for the `coordinateTapped` event and now that it is **working** I want to plot a marker on the map at the position at which I tap.

I cannot find an example of this online or in the sdk documentation.
I feel I am very close and just have a few minor corrections to make.

```
var mapsModule = require("nativescript-google-maps-sdk");

function onCoordinateTapped(args) {
    console.log("coordinate tapped!");
    var mapView = args.object;
    var marker = new mapsModule.Marker();
    marker.position = mapsModule.Position.positionFromLatLng(args.latitude,args.longitude);
    mapView.addMarker(marker);
}
```

**Note:** I've labelled this question with the `google-maps` tag as there is no `nativescript-google-maps` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Never it's too late to answer this kind of questions.

The problem was that the `args` object doesn't have a `latitude` nor a `longitude` attribute, so you are trying to add a marker with latitude and longitude as `undefined`.

Inside your function `onCoordinateTapped(args)` you can access to two different *positions*.

First, `args.object.latitude` and `args.object.longitude`.

```
var lat = args.object.latitude;
var lng = args.object.longitude;
```

Those attributes stand for the **current** position of the map (you know, the center of it).

Second, `args.position.latitude` and `args.position.longitude`.

```
var lat = args.position.latitude;
var lng = args.position.longitude;
```

In this case, those attributes represents the actual *position* of your tap on the map.

Also, this works on `coordinateLongPress`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this!

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Danoram you code looks'n'feels right and although there is no XML file I guess you have used the **coordinateEvent** to pass the fallback function ***onCoordinateTapped*** like [here](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/blob/master/demo/app/main-page.xml#L8)

```
<maps:mapView coordinateTapped="onCoordinateTapped" />
```

Is that working out for you or are you experiencing some kind of error/unexpected behaviour? It is not entirely clear from your post where the issue is...

Comment: Hi @Nick, yes you are correct. I have setup the callback function to the `coordinateTapped` event. The current functionality is that the console outputs "coordinate tapped!" when I tap the screen on my device but does not place a marker.

Comment: Will try to test the plugin demo once I obtain a Google API key.. meanwhile, if it applies to your case, you can use an alternative plugin like nativescript-geolocation. Example of how to add marker with it is here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/common-screens-category/lists-category/header-with-map/header-with-map.component.ts#L52-L59 ..will come back once I have a chance to test the nativescript-google-maps-sdk

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I'll try give the geolocation plugin a go when I next have a chance. What my friend and I are ultimately trying to achieve with the app is to use google map's "traffic layer" feature to determine the travel time between two points. I'm not even sure if this is possible using the nativescript maps sdk.